# css flexible middle column layout

Tags: html, css

How to make `.col2` flexible so it will fill space between `.col1` and `.col3`. I tried percents, but it doesn't work. What's the best way to achieve this? Thanks.

```css
body{
 margin:0;
}
.header{
 width:100%;
 background:gray;
 height:120px;
 margin:0 auto;
}
.MainController{
 width:100%;
 clear:both;
}
 .col1{
 height:679px;
 background:yellow;
 width:150px;
 float:left;
}
.col2{
 height:679px;
 background:black;
 float:left;
 width:20%;
}
.col3{
 height:679px;
 background:red;
 width:300px;
 float:right;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="header"></div>
 <div class="MainController">
  <div class="col1"></div>
  <div class="col2"></div>
  <div class="col3"></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Method 1: Using `calc`:

You could calculate the width with `calc`. The `.col2` will be 100% of the width minus the width of the two columns. So in this case:

```
calc: (100% - 450px); /*150px + 300px = 450px*/
```

Your code becomes:

```css
body{
 margin:0;
}
.header{
 width:100%;
 background:gray;
 height:120px;
 margin:0 auto;
}
.MainController{
 width:100%;
 clear:both;
}
 .col1{
 height:679px;
 background:yellow;
 width:150px;
 float:left;
}
.col2{
 height:679px;
 background:black;
 float:left;
 width:calc(100% - 450px);
}
.col3{
 height:679px;
 background:red;
 width:300px;
 float:right;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="header"></div>
 <div class="MainController">
  <div class="col1"></div>
  <div class="col2"></div>
  <div class="col3"></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

#### Method 2: Using `flexbox`:

You could also use `flexbox` like Aziz suggested.

Just set your `.col2` to have `flex:1` and your `.MainController` to have `display:flex`. Like so:

```css
body{
 margin:0;
}
.header{
 width:100%;
 background:gray;
 height:120px;
 margin:0 auto;
}
.MainController{
 width:100%;
 clear:both;
    display: flex;
}
 .col1{
 height:679px;
 background:yellow;
 width:150px;
 float:left;
}
.col2{
 height:679px;
 background:black;
 float:left;
    flex: 1;
}
.col3{
 height:679px;
 background:red;
 width:300px;
 float:right;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="header"></div>
 <div class="MainController">
  <div class="col1"></div>
  <div class="col2"></div>
  <div class="col3"></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

#### Browser support

Both methods are widely supported, however you might still want to check browser support here.

[**calc() support**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)

[**flexbox support**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Flexbox` layout. Apply `display: flex` to parent and add `flex: 1` to `.col2` to make it expand dynamically.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.header {
  width: 100%;
  background: gray;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.MainController {
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  display: flex;
}
.col1 {
  height: 679px;
  background: yellow;
  width: 150px;
}
.col2 {
  flex: 1;
  background: black;
  width: 20%;
}
.col3 {
  background: red;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="MainController">
    <div class="col1"></div>
    <div class="col2"></div>
    <div class="col3"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```